# Convert Tz posix time zone string to Utc-xx && vice versa

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, posix

anybody knows how to convert a tz posix time zone string example "CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3"
to an utc string like "(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West" in javascript

and the other way around ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you use a lookup?

http://code.google.com/p/x-wrt/source/browse/trunk/package/webif/files/usr/lib/webif/timezones.csv?r=2936

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/HkbAy/)

Comment: yeah it's the solution am using now but still i have to include all the tz databse in my js. though maybe there is another solution around, but thanks anyway for your answer , am accepting it.